# Unit Testing Controller that uses GetUserASync (User)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I am trying to Unit Test that a controller action returns the correct view. I am using .NET Core, Moq, and NUnit.

I want test the default `ManageController`,

The Constructor is below,

```
public ManageController(
  UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
  SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
  IEmailSender emailSender,
  ILogger<ManageController> logger,
  UrlEncoder urlEncoder)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _logger = logger;
    _urlEncoder = urlEncoder;
}
```

And am trying to Unit Test the following `Index` Action, and Assert that it returns the correct ViewModel when successful. (And will add other paths that return different ViewModels in future)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Username = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        IsEmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed,
        StatusMessage = StatusMessage
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

After many attempts, my closest solution is as follows,

I have mocked, `UserManager`, and Setup the `GetUserASync` method with a `ClaimsPrincipal` with the Id "1". I have also set the `HttpContext` to use the same `ClaimsPrincipal` and passed that the the controller.

As the Action is async, I was forced to make the test method async. Currently the test fails due to the async `Task` that is returned being null. I can't see if the rest of the test passes as I can't get past this error.

```
[Test]
public async Task Index_UserExists_ReturnsViewAsync()
{
     var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
     var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "1"),
    }));

    mockUserManager.Setup(x => x.GetUserAsync(user));

    var controller = new ManageController(mockUserManager.Object, null, null, null, null)
    {
        ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = user }
        }
    };

    //Act
    var result = await controller.Index();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the mock to return a task so that it can be awaited and allow the code to flow as intended

```
//...

var appUser = new ApplicationUser {
    //...populate as needed
}

 mockUserManager
    .Setup(_ => _.GetUserAsync(user))
    .ReturnsAsync(appUser); // Allows mocked member to be awaited and return desired type

//...
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I had tried 
    mockUserManager
    .Setup(_ => _.GetUserAsync(user))
    .Returns(appUser);

but hit what now feels like an obvious error with async returing a task not a user. didnt think to make it RetrunAsync()